# subscript out of range error in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to VBA so I have 2 questions:

1. Will the CSV file be automatically created or do I have to create the file name as "myfile" manually?
2. Why is there a *"subscript out of range"* error?

[image: Screenshot of Excel spreadsheet]

```
Sub LoadNewValuesAndCheckForChange()

    Dim rngMyValues As Range
    Dim varBefore As Variant
    Dim varAfter As Variant
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim iCol As Long
    Dim booValuesHaveChanged As Boolean

    Set rngMyValues = Range("A1:D96") ' Or wherever your data is

    varBefore = rngMyValues ' Save old values in an array

    ' Call the function that loads your new stock prices here...

    varAfter = rngMyValues ' Get new values

    ' Loop through all cells to see if anything has changed.
    booValuesHaveChanged = False
    For iRow = LBound(varBefore, 1) To UBound(varBefore, 1)
    For iCol = LBound(varBefore, 1) To UBound(varBefore, 1)
        If Not varAfter(iRow, iCol) = varBefore(iRow, iCol) Then
            ' Change detected!
            booValuesHaveChanged = True
            End If
        Next iCol
    Next iRow

    If booValuesHaveChanged Then
        ' Save .csv file with timestamp in filename
        ActiveWorksheet.SaveAs _
            Filename:="c:\myfile" & Format(Now, "yyyymmddhhnnss") & ".csv", _
           FileFormat:=xlCSV
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You should explain what this code is supposed to do, what it actually does and if there is an error, what line the error is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

1) The File will automatically be created.

2) Your getting the "subscript is out of range" error because your UBound for the       object varBefore is 10, so the object iCol is going to 10 when you only have 4 columns containing text or values. Debug your old code with F8 and hover over the iCol object when you get the error. You will see what I am talking about.

I changed your code a little bit and it works on my end:

```
Sub LoadNewValuesAndCheckForChange()

    Dim rngMyValues As Range
    Dim rngMyValues2 As Range
    Dim varBefore As Variant
    Dim varAfter As Variant
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim iCol As Long
    Dim oldwbk As Workbook
    Dim newwbk As Workbook

Set oldwbk = ThisWorkbook
' Call the function that loads your new stock prices here...
' This assumes that new stock prices are listed in another excel workbook
Set newwbk = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\mvanover\Desktop\Test\New Stock Prices.xlsx")
oldwbk.Activate
Set rngMyValues = Range("A1:D10") ' Or wherever your data is
varBefore = rngMyValues ' Save old values in an array

newwbk.Activate
Set rngMyValues2 = Range("A1:D10")
varAfter = rngMyValues2 ' Get new values

booValuesHaveChanged = False
' Loop through all cells to see if anything has changed.
' Remember, you only have 4 columns. This for loop would have to change if you added additional rows.
For iRow = LBound(varBefore, 1) To UBound(varBefore, 1)
For iCol = 1 To 4
    If Not varAfter(iRow, iCol) = varBefore(iRow, iCol) Then
        MsgBox "Change detected!"
        booValuesHaveChanged = True
        End If
    Next iCol
Next iRow


If booValuesHaveChanged Then
    ' Save .csv file with timestamp in filename
    newwbk.SaveAs _
        Filename:="C:\Users\mvanover\Desktop\Test\" & Format(Now(), "yyyymmddhhnnss") & "Stock Change.csv", _
       FileFormat:=xlCSV, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False
       ActiveWorkbook.Save
End If

End Sub
```